# how to input structural type vector data into structural vector member (nested structural vector) in c++

Tags: c++, vector, visual-studio-2017

I'm beginner and implementing scheduling simulation. 
I want to insert the structural vector(Order) into the structural member vector(selectedParts) in the Pallet.

I know how to insert the int type vector (fixtureTypes) into the structure Pallet But i don't know how to insert the structural type vector (selectedParts) into the Pallet.
I'd appreciate it if someone let me know how to solve it.

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<Pallet> pallets;
    int tmpFixtureType;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        Pallet pallet;
        pallet.palletNo = i;
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
        {
            cin >> tmpFixtureType;
            pallet.fixtureTypes.push_back(tmpFixtureType);
        }
        pallets.push_back(pallet);  //end the "pallet.fixtureTypes.push_back" loop

   }

   for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)     //and then input the "selectedParts" in pallets
   {
       Order tmpOrder;
       tmpOrder.partNo = j;
       tmpOrder.partType = j;
       pallet.selectedParts.push_back(tmpOrder);
   }
   pallets.push_back(pallet);

}
```

Comment: Perhaps you meant to nest the loops.

Comment: I want to inherit structural vector data to structural vectors in any way. Do you know the easy way to inherit this type of structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting is that `pallet` as a name does not have meaning outside the scope (`{` to `}`) where it is defined. You have *multiple* `Pallet` instances, you need to think about *which one* you are dealing with.

Moving your `Order` population to the scope where `pallet` is defined is simple.

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<Pallet> pallets;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        Pallet pallet;
        pallet.palletNo = i;
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
        {
            int tmpFixtureType;
            cin >> tmpFixtureType;
            pallet.fixtureTypes.push_back(tmpFixtureType);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        {
            Order tmpOrder;
            tmpOrder.partNo = j;
            tmpOrder.partType = j;
            pallet.selectedParts.push_back(tmpOrder);
        }
        pallets.push_back(pallet);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is unclear what you are trying to do, and on top of that, the code does not even compile as it stands. I will offer some suggestions and perhaps this works for you.

1. Follow a standard naming convention (I prefer camelCase). Make sure to distinguish between types and instances.
2. Don't worry about reserving space for vector or moving objects at first.

Note that I refactored your code (mainly renamed variables and types)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Order {
    int partNo;
    int dueDate;
    int partType;
    int pallet;
};

struct Pallet {
    int palletNo;
    std::vector<int> fixtureTypes;
    std::vector<Order> selectedParts;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Pallet> pallets;
    int tmpFixtureType;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        Pallet pallet;
        pallet.palletNo = i;
        Order tmpOrder;
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
        {
            cin >> tmpFixtureType;
            pallet.fixtureTypes.push_back(tmpFixtureType);

            tmpOrder.partNo = j;
            tmpOrder.partType = j;
            pallet.selectedParts.push_back(tmpOrder);
        }

        pallets.push_back(pallet);
    }
}
```

See if this is what you want. You can go from there.

Comment: nikiya. I leave the answer for your comment. 
If you have time, please check it.